# Determine whether JRE is installed using Install4j

Tags: java, deployment, installation, install4j

I have created an installer for my Java app using Install4j.

I want to check whether JRE/JDK is installed on my system or not. This checking will be performed at the start-up of the installer. So how can i do that ?

And help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you can turn it around and do the check prior to downloading the installer.. The best way to write the down-load link is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).  It can check for a particular minimum version of Java (and prompt the user to install it) before writing the link.  It means both a smaller distributable for you, & the user gets whatever security updates might be available.

Comment: I am not familiar with "Deployment Toolkit Script", and I think it's not what I want. Because my installer isn't a web installer, It's a standalone desktop installer. At the startup of the installer i want to detect whether JRE/JDK is installed on my system or not. If not then i want give the user an option to download JRE. So can you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: *"It's a standalone desktop installer"*  OK - I get that.  How do you intend to deliver it from you to the client computer?

Comment: I will just provide only the installer to the users. I have packed everything(external jars, icon etc) that is needed to run my app.

Comment: *"I will just provide only the installer to the users."*  OK I get that, but how will you supply the software to the user?  Internet site?  Intranet site?  You visiting the client with a flash drive?  Sending them a flash drive? CD/DVD? Floppy disk?  [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)? (My personal favorite.) ..

Comment: May be through Internet site or email or like this. But i don't think it's such a big deal. Actually I don't find any relation between this distribution method and checking JRE.

Comment: *"May be through Internet site or email or like this."* Both those methods require the internet to deliver either the installer or the installer + (inbuilt) JRE. *"But i don't think it's such a big deal."*  My point is that using the deployment toolkit script is a way to better deliver the JRE (by the same method - internet).  Even better, if the minimum version is 1.6.0_10+ and the user already has a 1.7.0_21 JRE installed, then the user can get the application, totally free of any JRE download (e.g. via email attachment).

Comment: OK, I got that. But at this time I just need to know that how can I do it in install4j. 

And thank you very much for this.

Comment: (shrugs) I don't use Install4J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j always checks whether a suitable JRE is available, otherwise it cannot run. If no suitable JRE is available, an error message will be displayed.

If you do not want to statically bundle a JRE into the installer, you can use the "dynamic bundle" option that will download the JRE on demand. This is configured on the "Bundled JRE" step of the media wizard.

Comment: _"If no suitable JRE is available, an error message will be displayed."_  >>  Can i change/modify that error message as my own ? If yes then from where and how can I do that ?

Comment: General Settings->Languages, set up a custom localization file, override the message with key "exe4j.NoJvmFound3264".